# how can I accesses AWS athena with lambda of other region even s3 is in another region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, amazon-athena

I have to access AWS Athena which  is in a different region, whereas I want to access it through lambda which is in another region also output s3 bucket is in the region where lambda is there how can I do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what language you are using in your lambda but for python you dot it be specifying the region when you create your athena client.

You can read more here:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html

Comment: "An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the StartQueryExecution operation: The S3 location provided to save your query results is invalid. Please check your S3 location is correct and is in the same region and try again. If you continue to see the issue, contact customer support for further assistance.", 
This error is coming when my output s3 bucket is in different region